# Is it possible to delegate methods implementations

Tags: function, kotlin, lambda, reflection, delegates

Given a function which creates lambdas. Is it possible to delegate the implementation of a declared function to a returned lambda (analogue to `by`-delegated properties). If `by` would exist for functions it could look like this:

```
fun printFunCreator(message: String): () -> Unit  = { println(message) }
fun printHelloWorld() by printFunCreator("Hello world")
```

#### What I am not looking for:

I do **not** want to create an extra property of the lambda to delegate the call like this:

```
fun printFunCreator(message: String): () -> Unit  = { println(message) }
val printFun = printFunCreator("Hello world")
fun printHelloWorld() = printFun.invoke()
```

And I do **not** want to create a new lambda instance for each execution like this:

```
fun printFunCreator(message: String): () -> Unit  = { println(message) }
fun printHelloWorld() = printFunCreator("Hello world").invoke()
```

Comment: There is no function delegation like `fun funName() by ... `  in kotlin [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html), [delegated-properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

The description of what you want sounds like simply doing this:

```
fun printFunCreator(message: String) { println(message) }
fun printHelloWorld() = printFunCreator("Hello world")
```

Unless there is some reason `printFunCreator()` has to return a lambda...?

Comment: A Property is not a solution for me. I need input parameters too: `fun countFunCreator(start: Int): () -> Unit { var count = start; return { println("count ${count++}") } }`

Comment: @user1185087 I missed that detail. Updated answer. Maybe I need more clarification of what you want and the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```java
fun printFunCreator(message: String): () -> Unit  = { println(message) }
val printHelloWorld = printFunCreator("Hello World")
```

Then you can use syntax similar to function call in your code:

```java
printHelloWorld()
```

You neither delegate a function call to property (because this way there is no function, only a property that you can call like a function) nor create a lambda for each execution.